# Applying a COUNTIF to a COUNTUNIQUEIFS using variable Date Ranges

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, countif, count-unique

I have a sheet that can calculate the months and years using COUNTIFS, where I can select the year using a dropdown. However, I am looking to apply the same method to count UNIQUE names (Column B) within the same month and year I ave selected (Column A), maintaining the same dropdown method.

[Here is the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kSz2sFcSEugp73ji7Bf5j8YAhZpoQj7zqk-4Gp-sJAI/edit#gid=0). Is this possible? Thank you!

| + | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Select Year | 2023 |  | January | February | March | April | May | June |
| 2 |  |  |  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 3 |  |  | formula→ | 2 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 4 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 6 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 7 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 8 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 11 | Date | Name |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | 1-Jan-2023 | Burger King |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 13 | 7-Jun-2022 | Sonic |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | 1-Jan-2023 | Burger King |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 15 | 4-Feb-2023 | McDonalds |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 16 | 6-Feb-2023 | McDonalds |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 17 | 13-Feb-2023 | Dairy Queen |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 18 | 3-Mar-2023 | Wendy's |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 19 | 23-Mar-2023 | McDonalds |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 20 | 3-Apr-2023 | Dairy Queen |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 21 | 3-Jun-2023 | Sonic |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 22 | 3-Mar-2024 | Wendy's |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 23 | 23-Mar-2024 | McDonalds |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(D1:I1,lambda(x,index(countuniqueifs(B12:B,eomonth(A12:A,),eomonth(date(B1,month(x),1),)))))
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome, thank you! and what if I wanted to filter just by the selected year?

Comment: try: `=arrayformula(countuniqueifs(B12:B,year(A12:A),B1))`